# Group by based on user id and their interactions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Dataset and Notebook file : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14z16wOEjKe299oSxu_wlh5Zr-dfbnXgE?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me out on this?

I have dataframe (named as dfm2)

**THIS IS THE HEAD OF DATAFRAME**
[image: Dataframe Head]

**THIS IS THE TAIL OF DATAFRAME**
[image: DataFrame Tail]

I wanna see how much each user has attempted total questions and how many are correct & incorrect? and plot this as Y axis could be percentage and X axis should be each user.

questions_id : Contains question number
user_answer : Contains what user has answered to that question (a , b , c or d)

user_iD : this identifies each each

correct_answer : it's basically the answer key.

user_correct : it's 0 if user answer is incorrect and 1 if user answers correctly

What I have tried so far

```
df_total_questions_attempted = dfm2.groupby(['user_iD'])['question_id'].count().to_frame('Total Questions Attempted')

df_correct = dfm2[dfm2['user_correct']==1].groupby(['user_iD'])['question_id'].count().to_frame('Correct')

df_incorrect = dfm2[dfm2['user_correct']==0].groupby(['user_iD'])['question_id'].count().to_frame('Incorrect')

df = pd.concat([df_total_questions_attempted, df_correct, df_incorrect], axis=1).fillna(0)

df['Percentage'] = (df['Correct'] / df['Total Questions Attempted']) *100
```

**THIS IS THE OUTPUT I GET**

[image]

The problem with this output is that it's making user_iD as index and not a column and secondly user_iD's are not as 1,2,3,4,5.....
Let me post the user_ID head too

[image]

It doesn't returns the expected output , it should take user_iD from the dataframe (dfm2) and make it as a column not an index

**THIS IS THE EXPECTED OUTPUT**
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could provide some sample data instead of the image. Images are not the best way to ask a question as it makes it difficult to read/reproduce.

Comment: @heretolearn : Added a link to the dataset and notebook file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid user_id being set as index, use `as_index=False` in the `groupby` like:

```
df_total_questions_attempted = dfm2.groupby(['user_iD'], as_index=False)['question_id'].count()
```

By default the values are sorted on the groupby keys, in case you don't want the values to be sorted, set the `sort=False`

```
df_total_questions_attempted = dfm2.groupby(['user_iD'], 
                               sort=False, as_index=False)['question_id'].count()
```

Comment: After doing that as_index=False
I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: sorry, Updated my answer. If you use `as_index=False`  you don't have to use `to_frame` to get the dataframe.

Comment: Again, if you could provide me some data to work with, it would be easier to help you with the issue. Reading it from image is not very helpful.

Comment: But it still giving me user_iD as 1,2,3,4..... Although as a column but not the user's which are present in the dataframe

Comment: Where should i send you the data?

Comment: you could add a sample data to the question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14z16wOEjKe299oSxu_wlh5Zr-dfbnXgE?usp=sharing 
here's the link to the data and notebook file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235966/discussion-between-heretolearn-and-haseeb-sultan).